# This keyword is not pointing to the current object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a react application where I am getting the property from the parent component, but when I try to set the state of the child using this.props, I am getting props is undefined error. I can understand that somehow this is not pointing to the current object. Can you please help me in resolving this issue. Thanks !!!

**Error in the below line**

```
count: this.props.value,
```

**Full Code Below**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { throwStatement } from "@babel/types";

class Counter extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    var self = this;

    this.incrementButtonClick = this.incrementButtonClick.bind(this);
    this.incrementDoubleClick = this.incrementDoubleClick.bind(this);
  }

  state = {
    count: this.props.value,
    tags: ["Markers", "Books", "Board"]
  };

  mySpanstyle = {
    fontSize: 10,
    color: "yellow"
  };

  render() {
    console.log("props ", this.props.value);
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <span className={this.getSpanClass()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
        <button
          onDoubleClick={this.incrementDoubleClick}
          /* onClick={this.incrementButtonClick} */
          onClick={() => {
            this.incrementButtonClick("TEST");
          }}
          className="btn btn-primary"
        >
          Increment
        </button>
        <br></br>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

  incrementButtonClick(e) {
    console.log("Increment button clicked", e);
    console.log(this.state.count);
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  }

  incrementDoubleClick() {
    console.log("Increment button Double clicked", this);
  }

  getSpanClass() {
    return this.state.count === 0
      ? "badge badge-warning m-2"
      : "badge badge-info m-2";
  }

  getMethod() {
    var value = () => {
      console.log("values ", this.props.value);
    };
  }

  formatCount() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return count === 0 ? "Zero" : count;
  }
}
export default Counter;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `constructor` needs to accept `props` and your state should be initialized inside the constructor:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.incrementButtonClick = this.incrementButtonClick.bind(this);
    this.incrementDoubleClick = this.incrementDoubleClick.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      count: this.props.value,
      tags: ["Markers", "Books", "Board"]
    };
  }
```

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.incrementButtonClick = this.incrementButtonClick.bind(this);
    this.incrementDoubleClick = this.incrementDoubleClick.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      count: this.props.value,
      tags: ["Markers", "Books", "Board"]
    };
  }

  mySpanstyle = {
    fontSize: 10,
    color: "yellow"
  };

  render() {
    console.log("props ", this.props.value);
    return ( <
      React.Fragment >
      <
      span className = {
        this.getSpanClass()
      } > {
        this.formatCount()
      } < /span> <
      button onDoubleClick = {
        this.incrementDoubleClick
      }
      /* onClick={this.incrementButtonClick} */
      onClick = {
        () => {
          this.incrementButtonClick("TEST");
        }
      }
      className = "btn btn-primary" >
      Increment <
      /button> <
      br / >
      <
      /React.Fragment>
    );
  }

  incrementButtonClick(e) {
    console.log("Increment button clicked", e);
    console.log(this.state.count);
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    });
  }

  incrementDoubleClick() {
    console.log("Increment button Double clicked", this);
  }

  getSpanClass() {
    return this.state.count === 0 ?
      "badge badge-warning m-2" :
      "badge badge-info m-2";
  }

  getMethod() {
    var value = () => {
      console.log("values ", this.props.value);
    };
  }

  formatCount() {
    const {
      count
    } = this.state;
    return count === 0 ? "Zero" : count;
  }
}

function App() {
  return ( <
    Counter value = {
      1
    }
    />
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: i would probably rephrase it to *state should be initialized inside the constructor*.

Comment: If you are using `props` in a `constructor` you don't need to use `this`. You can directly do this `count: props.value,`